# AngularJs, how to assign dynamic model name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, binding, model

I wanna create a dynamic table (say 5X5 ) containing a checkbox matrix, and assign each checkbox with a model,

```
<tr ng-repeat="parentItem in Items>
      <td>{{parentItem.name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="childItem in Items>                         
       <input id="{{ parentItem.id }}_{{childItem.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="data['{{ parentItem.id }}_{{childItem.id}}']">
       </td>
</tr>
```

In the controller, a data object is defined as `$scope.data={};`

so what I expect is that each checkbox will end with a model in a form like `data['1_3']` or `data['2_4']`,
I tried many ways but the model just could not be bound correctly.

Actually, tried this way 
`data[parentItem.id]`, 
it worked, but no idea how to concatenate two dynamic items.

Comment: please post your code in Fiddle

Comment: Try: `ng-model="data[parentItem.id + '_' + childItem.id]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it but `ng-model="data[parentItem.id + '_' + childItem.id]"` should work.

Generally for `ngModel` you don't need to use `{{}}`

Comment: it is working, thanks! I tried data[parentItem.id + "_" + childItem.id] but failed, it is single quote that does the magic.